# Error when installing Ctypes package into python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get an error when trying to install `ctypes` package in python 3.10.8. I tried every solution I could find but nothing worked.

I tried using
`pip install ctypes`
I also tried using another name in case they changed the name
`pip install ctype`

Comment: Why do you not just use the one that's included in the standard library?

Answer (score 3):

[The `ctypes` module available on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ctypes/) was last released in May, 2007. It is *ancient*.

[`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) has been bundled with Python [since version 2.5](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5/highlights/). You don't need to install it separately. Just use it.